Error: The request matched multiple endpoints, when I inherit from BaseController
I created a BaseController to control access to methods of all child controllers, and it is in the following code:
    public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        protected readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        protected ControllerPermission ControllerPermission { get; set; }
        
        private string controllerName;

        public BaseController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;

            controllerName = this.GetType().Name[..^10];
            ControllerPermission = _unitOfWork.ControllerPermission.GetFirstOrDefault(
               x => x.Name == controllerName);
        }

        public virtual IActionResult Add()
        {
            if (ControllerPermission.IsAdd)
            {
                return NoContent();
            }

            return RedirectToPage("/NotAllowed");
        }

        public virtual IActionResult Edit()
        {
            if (!ControllerPermission.IsEdit)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Project");
            }

            return NoContent();
        }

        public virtual IActionResult Delete()
        {
            if (ControllerPermission.IsDelete)
            {
                return NoContent();
            }

            return RedirectToPage("/NotAllowed");
        }
    }

And I created a ProjectController:
[BindProperties]
public class ProjectController : BaseController
{
    public IEnumerable<Project>? Projects { get; set; }
    public Project? Project { get; set; }

    public ProjectController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) : base (unitOfWork)
    {
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        Projects = _unitOfWork.Project.GetAll();
        return View(Projects);
    }

    public IActionResult Details()
    {
        return View(Project);
    }

    public override IActionResult Add()
    {
        base.Add();

        if (Request.Method == "POST" && Project != null)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _unitOfWork.Project.Add(Project);
                _unitOfWork.Save();
            }
        }

        return View(Project);
    }

    public override IActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        base.Edit();

        if (Request.Method == "POST" && Project != null)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _unitOfWork.Project.Update(Project);
                _unitOfWork.Save();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Project = _unitOfWork.Project.GetFirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Project");
    }

    public override IActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        base.Delete();

        if (Request.Method == "POST" && Project != null)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _unitOfWork.Project.Remove(Project);
                _unitOfWork.Save();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Project = _unitOfWork.Project.GetFirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        }

        return View(Project);
    }
}

As you can see in the previous code, the BaseController reads a record from DB to get the permission of the child controller. The permission values of ProjectController are:

IsView -> True
IsAdd -> True
IsEdit -> False
IsDelete -> False

It is working fine with Add() method because it returns NoContent() when IsAdd is true but, it gives me the error "The request matched multiple endpoints" when I try to access Edit() method because IsEdit is false
I tried to return RedirectToPage from the child class ProjectController to see if the RedirectToPage is the issue but it wasn't.
I would appreciate any help.
Thank you guys.

Your Edit code should check if the base function is returning type RedirectToActionResult
Use the code below
public override IActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        // check if the base function is returning a redirect
        var result = base.Edit();
        var parseResult = result as RedirectToActionResult;
        if (parseResult != null)
           return RedirectToAction(parseResult.ActionName, parseResult.ControllerName);        

        if (Request.Method == "POST" && Project != null)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _unitOfWork.Project.Update(Project);
                _unitOfWork.Save();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Project = _unitOfWork.Project.GetFirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Project");
    }


If the code above works, you can try exploring another implementation which are Action Filters. They're executed before/after a request arrives to the controller.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-8.0
How to use Action Filters with Dependency Injection in ASP.NET CORE?

I am sorry, I have it there already the "override" keyword but I think I accidentally deleted it. And it still doesn't redirect me to (NotAllowed) Page.

@YousifAl-Zoubi updated the answer
